# import from external folder in python using cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

How do I import a module using python in a cygwin shell. I want to import from a folder either outside or inside Cygwin drive?
I tried `>>> from cygdrive.c.directory.file but got an error :`

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cygdrive'

Comment: import what ? How you built or obtained the module ?

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: I see no difference. `import` requires a package name not a file name and it must be in well defined directories

Comment: Okay. It has a package name. What do you mean by well defined?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8.8 on cygwin uses the following directories to look
for modules:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/Marco/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>>
```

Comment: Yes. So can I get it to look to an external directory?